# Is there an online Q/A forum for the philosophy of mathematical practice?

Tags: philosophy

Certain philosophers of mathematics are interested in aspects of [the philosophy of mathematical practice.](http://www.ams.org/notices/201203/rtx120300424p.pdf) Mathematicians, perhaps, would be interested in philosophy that may affect their day to day work, as is noted near the end of Gowers's article on [whether mathematics needs a philosophy](https://www.dpmms.cam.ac.uk/~wtg10/philosophy.html).

JDH's curiosity about structuralism on a recent Bourbaki thread on MathOverflow makes me wonder:

> **Question:** Is there an appropriate "stack exchange" for questions on the philosophy of mathematical practice?

I think questions about the philosophy of mathematics are inappropriate for MO in general, but may be interesting for mathematicians if handled elsewhere. Unfortunately, philosophy.stackexchange doesn't seem very helpful for the type of question I'm thinking of. I'm also not interested in a site that is dominated by questions targeting old foundational issues more than contemporary practice. I imagine, also, that many naive questions would populate such a forum and so am not necessarily suggesting that one would be a good idea.

I think the answer below settles the question adequately. It was not much effort, however, to propose a stack exchange for philosophy of mathematics at Area 51:

http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/48664/philosophy-of-mathematics

Answer (score 3):

I think it is not an accident that philosophy.stackexchange is so very uninspiring (to put it tactfully!). Philosophy really isn't the sort of enquiry which in general lends itself very well to the stack exchange format, which is most appropriate for inviting short sharp technical answers to focused questions, and not so apt for exploring conceptually complex, ramifying, debates. And what applies to philosophy generally applies to philosophy of mathematics in particular.

Still, that's no reason not to pose specific questions here or at mathoverflow.net when broadly philosophical/conceptual questions and technical concerns do entwine, and you might get some really good responses (think e.g. of some of Joel David Hamkins's contributions over at mathoverflow).

Comment: Decent answer imo. If you want to discuss mathamtical philosophy, why not use http://forums.philosophyforums.com/logic-and-philosophy-of-math/ for example?

Comment: I am particularly interested in the Alethiology (the study of truth) of mathematics. Now that I have searched for the above forum, I might actually join it and ask a question I have been meaning to ask. Thanks Jon and Peter!

Comment: I don't know that site, but at least *here* it is a good idea to allow some reading and thinking time between "join it" and "ask a question".